# c++ storing a pointer to an object in a node of BST

Tags: c++

a pointer to a car object (which contains my data) is stored in my node of the BST.

car base class has derived classes electric, petrol and diesel

how can I search for a car of a particular type in the tree with a key from this object pointer? What needs to be included in the car.cpp?

```
struct node
{

Car *ptr
node *left
node *right

}
```

Comment: You need some kind of ordering criteria to build the tree in the first place. You use the same criteria to search.

Comment: Indeed. I'm guessing a left node would branch to `electric`, and a right node would branch to `oil`, whose branches are `petrol` and `diesel`. From that point, it would be trivial (you would have the state stored when you do your search)

Comment: how would that work in terms of balancing the tree? Would you balance each sub tree ( electric and oil)

Answer (score 0):

If you store data as pointers only (using BST logic) and then want to search, you can not. Pointer holds no additional information about content of object. Two objects can be the same, but their pointers are different.
You will have to change BST inserting mechanic. Best way would be to comute some kind of hash from your object. But for that case, BST is not really a good structure.. HashMaps are imho way better.

Comment: the pointer is pointing to a car object, which has things like make model etc. I know what you mean. Thank you